# Associate Core Data Objects based on matching Dates

Tags: ios, core-data, database-design

I've designed my first database using Core Data. Consider the flow chart on the right of the attached image. It describes an algorithm to connect EntryType objects (light blue) with Day objects. Trouble is I don't know how to implement it.

What I would like to do is create a new Core Data Entity "Day" and associate it TrainingEntries, WaterEntries, MealEntries, etc when they are being created by the user in realtime through the UI. If there is already a "Day" object with a calendar date matching the new Entries date property associate the two together via core data relationships. Then I can just pass "Day" objects to my TableView and detailViews and use CoreData to traverse the graph as needed.

1. Is there a way to execute some code when an EntryType object is created in Core Data at the database level?
2. How do I then associate "Days" with "Entries" based on their date property?
3. How do I tell "Day" to recalculate it's properties after a "Entry" is added?

Thanks in Advance. It's easiest to save the image and open it in Preview.

=)
[image: Object Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Addressing each question individually:

1. Yes you can.  Checkout the awakeFromInsert method on [NSManagedObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html)
2. Since you have a day entity and an entry entity, it's simply a 1 to many relationship days->entries.  Though I have not used it CoreData supports abstract entities which you might try.  That way MealEntry, TrainingEntry, etc can all extend the base entry entity.  If you're thinking about CoreData as an object graph the entries are a relationship on "day"
3. What you're probably looking for is a transient property, one that's not a stored field but is computed based on other values.